# Unexpected undefined result

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I'm trying to go through an array of objects to extract two properties to another object. I have the following function to achieve this. While it works for the nested property correctly, I cant extract non-nested property and keep getting undefined.

```
const formatPhonesArray = (array) => {
  console.log(array);
  let resultArray = [];
  for (const phone of array) {
    resultArray.push({
      operator: phone.operator.name,
      phone: phone.number,
    });
  }
  console.log(resultArray);
  return resultArray;
};
```

And I have the following array

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6190ecde73b2623593666fbb"),
    number: '+38(067)341-32-92',
    operator: {
      _id: new ObjectId("616090760a30fb3f993b61b5"),
      name: 'Київстар',
      codes: [Array],
      __v: 0
    }
  }
]
```

But somehow it yelds this
`[ { operator: 'Київстар', phone: undefined } ]`
while I expect
`[ { operator: 'Київстар', phone: '+38(067)341-32-92'} ]`
and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You are showing three arrays, not one. The second array has the phone `undefined` so your loop will return `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong data. Just edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Output of that function given that array is `[ { "operator": "Київстар", "phone": "+38(067)341-32-92" } ]` as expected. Please post a minimal, self-contained example that demonstrates the failing behaviour.

Comment: It's basically a viber-bot. On receiving the text message it goes to Mongo DB and retrieves an array of objects which I want to parse in order to extract these two values from each object in an array. When I console.log result of the query, phone is there. But when I parse the result with this function, the nested operator value is still there, but the phone value yields undefined. Honestly, IDK how to post a relevant piece of code here to demonstrate this.

Comment: Since your code works, it must be the data that returns undefined, or has a different format than you expect. You could add `if (phone...)` statements to check if the value is there.

Comment: Tnx, I will try that.

Comment: After further investigation, I found out that this function works fine when I call it from inside of a synchronous function, but it fails after I call it from inside of an async-await function. Still have no idea why, though.

Answer (score 0):

No problem in your code
I got this result

```js
[
  {
    "operator": "Київстар",
    "phone": "+38(067)341-32-92"
  }
]
```

Its working